# Linq to Entities Distinct on Column without Anonymous Type

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, distinct, anonymous-types

I am using **Entity Framework 5.0** and I wish to return a list of objects, however, I want to perform a **DISTINCT on one of the properties** on each object within the list.

I know there are a few questions similar to mine already on **Stackoverflow**, however, I am still struggling with this one.

Currently my query looks like this

```
public IList<tblcours> GetAllCoursesByOrgID(int id)
{
     return _UoW.tblcoursRepo.All.Where(c => c.tblCourseCategoryLinks.Any(cl => cl.tblUnitCategory.tblUnit.ParentID == id))
            .OrderBy(c => c.CourseTitle)
            .ToList();
}
```

However, I need to perform a **DISTINCT** on the property **MainHeadingID** to remove any objects already with the same ID, **but still returning the entire object with all its properties**.

Preferably, I would like to return **IList**, as you can see from my method, and **not an Anonymous Type**.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using `GroupBy`?

```
_UoW.tblcoursRepo.All.GroupBy(c => c.MainHeadingId)
                     .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: fyi: Performance will not be good as the translation to SQL is awful. But it works so +1.