# Linq To Entities Optional Distinct

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, distinct

Earlier I put a [question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087531/linq-to-entities-distinct-on-column-without-anonymous-type) about how to **remove duplicate records in a list of objects**, based on a particular property within each object.

I got the answer I was looking for (see below), a **query which returns a distinct list** of objects **using MainHeadingID as the property to remove duplicates**.

```
public IList<tblcours> GetAllCoursesByOrgID(int id)
{
    return _UoW.tblcoursRepo.All.
        Where(c => c.tblCourseCategoryLinks.Any(cl => cl.tblUnitCategory.tblUnit.ParentID == id))
        .GroupBy(c => c.MainHeadingID)
        .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
        .ToList();
}
```

However, now I need more help! Is there anyway of amending the query above so that, it **only removes duplicate values when MainHeadingID is not equal to 180**. I tried amending GroupBy line to

```
.GroupBy(c => c.MainHeadingID != 180)
```

However, this didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following works for LINQ to SQL:

```
return _UoW.tblcoursRepo.All
   .Where(c => c.tblCourseCategoryLinks.Any(cl => cl.tblUnitCategory.tblUnit.ParentID == id))
   .GroupBy(c => c.MainHeadingID)
   //.SelectMany(g => g.Key == 180 ? g : g.Take(1))
   .SelectMany(g => g.Take(g.Key == 180 ? Int32.MaxValue : 1))
   .ToList();
```

*Comments:* `SelectMany` in query above selects all items from group where `MainHeadingID` equals to 180, but it takes only one item form other groups (i.e. distinct result). Linq to SQL cannot translate commented out part, but thanks to @usr there is way around.

---

Linq to Entities cannot translate even simplified query. I think only option for you in this case is simple concating result of two queries:

```
Expression<Func<tblcours, bool>> predicate = x =>
  x.tblCourseCategoryLinks.Any(cl => cl.tblUnitCategory.tblUnit.ParentID == id)
int headingId = 180;

return _UoW.tblcoursRepo.All
   .Where(c => c.MainHeadingID != headingId)
   .Where(predicate)
   .GroupBy(c => c.MainHeadingID)
   .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
   .Concat(_UoW.tblcoursRepo.All
               .Where(c => c.MainHeadingID == headingId)
               .Where(predicate))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: this looks good, but I get runtime error, A valid ResultType could not be inferred from the ResultTypes of the specified 'Then' expressions. Any ideas?

Comment: @tgriffiths hold on, I'll verify that

Comment: @tgriffiths :( looks like Linq cannot translate such expression into SQL, I'll check what could be done here

Comment: you can always use AsEnumerable to move LINQ to in-memory query

Comment: Any idea's how to actually implement the above suggestion?

Comment: @tgriffiths I've tried code from my updated answer, works without any problems

Comment: @lazyberezovsky unfortunately when I try your update I still get, Limit must be a DbConstantExpression or a DbParameterReferenceExpression.
Parameter name: limit. I don't understand why it works for you and not me :(

Comment: @tgriffiths I was checking that in LINQ Pad with Linq to SQL. I can't at the moment verify it with EF. I'll do it as soon as possible

Comment: @tgriffiths done! Looks like EF completely can't convert such query into SQL. That's definitely a bug. I've added solution that works in EF

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Great stuff. Your new strategy was what I was thinking myself, however, your code is much more efficient. Thanks very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

lazyberezovsky's answer fails due to an EF bug (which is not surprising given the quality of EF's LINQ support). It can be made to work with a hack:

```
.SelectMany(g => g.Key == 180 ? g.Take(int.MaxValue) : g.Take(1))
```

or

```
.SelectMany(g => g.Take(g.Key == 180 ? int.MaxValue : 1))
```

Note that performance will not be particularly good due to the way this is translated to SQL.

Comment: @usr - thanks for your help, but, when I try your 1st .SelectMany I get the following error The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect'. When I try the 2nd .SelectMany I get Limit must be a DbConstantExpression or a DbParameterReferenceExpression.
Parameter name: limit. Please help.

Comment: Ok in that case I surrender to EF's lack of features. I suggest you execute the query in memory, like lazyberezovsky already suggested. Performance might be even more awful then.

Comment: @usr - Ok. I've no idea how to execute the query in memory though.